# initializing private var creates AccessViolation

Tags: delphi

Comming from a C# background I'm trying to learn Delphi.
I encounter an Access violation when in my form I press a button that creates a TLight instance.
Wherever I try to access my private FState I get an access violation.

What am I missing?

```
unit Light;
interface
uses sysUtils;

type
  TLightStates = (Red, Orange, Green);
type
  TLight = class
    private
      Fstate : TLightStates;
    published
      Constructor Create(); overload;
      procedure SetState(const Value: TLightStates);
      Property State : TLightStates
        read Fstate
        write SetState;
  end;

implementation
{ TLight }
    constructor TLight.Create;
    begin
      Fstate := TLightStates.Red;
    end;

    procedure TLight.SetState(const Value: TLightStates);
    begin
      Fstate := Value;
    end;
end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you create an object in your test code where the property State is set?

```
var
  x: TLight;
begin
  x := TLight.Create;
  x.Light := Orange;
  x.Free; 
end;
```

Looking at the code this should work correctly.

One other thing: why did you specify the contructor with overload: you derive from TObject and it does not have a virtual constructor, so overload should not be specified here.

Comment: Aha, I didn't initialize it as in C# enums don't need to be created. The reason I'm overriding is because I saw it like that in the tutorial ;) I see now this is rather pointless. Thx

Comment: @Ritsaert - you actually meant override instead of overload; override causes syntax error when applied to non-virtual methods; overload can be applyed to any method, it is just pointless here.

Comment: >I didn't initialize it as in C# enums don't need to be created.

delphi enums don't need to be instantiated either.  in C# you can declare an object so it'll be created (and destroyed) automatically.  regrettably, delphi doesn't have this.

Answer (score 2):

One comment about the above piece of code :

```
var
  x: TLight;
begin
  x := TLight.Create;
  TRY  
    x.Light := Orange;
  FINALLY
    x.Free; 
  END;
end;
```

"try" and "finally" (uppercase used above for readability) ensure that x will be freed.
As you might know by now, there is no garbage collection in Delphi so freeing your objects is a **must**...

About your initial piece of code :
Your create should be virtual and public.
Minor comments :

1. TLightStates = (Red, Orange, Green)
   should actually be    TLightState =
   (Red, Orange, Green) (no "s" since
   adding an "s" would usually mean a
   set of TLightState)
2. Your SetState procedure should ideally be protected instead of
   published.

hth,
kuzkot

Comment: There is absolutely no need to declare Create as a virtual constructor - that is at least pointless.

Comment: -1. Does not answer the question, and is overly pedantic about code that's really just fine. Please use *comments* for things that aren't related to the question at hand. (You'll be allowed to post comments once you earn just a little more reputation points.) Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Agreed that this should have been a comment. But "overly pedantic"? I see some valid points - try-finally, enum naming convention, not making setters published.